# How do applications like Google Sidebar reduce the desktop size?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to write an application which will sit at the top of the desktop on top of every window. I need this window however to *not* just sit on top of other windows, but to actually reduce the size of the desktop so when these windows maximise they don't get covered up by my application's bar.

So, basically, I want my application's window behaviour to match that of the Windows taskbar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. These windows are known as Application Desktop Toolbars. MSDN has a reference page on them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx).